# Rename File Based on Portion of Directory Name using zsh

Tags: shell, directory, zsh, file-rename

I would like to rename a file in a directory based upon a portion of the directory name. I have the following structure:

```
Sample_1234/all_R2.gz
Sample_2345/all_R2.gz
Sample_3456/all_R2.gz
```

In each directory I create a new file from concatenation of multiple other files. I would then like to name the new concated file using only the number portion of the directory name. For example,

```
Sample_1234/1234_R2.gz
Sample_2345/2345_R2.gz
Sample_3456/3456_R2.gz
```

I can return the portion of the directory name that I want with:

```
pwd | grep -o '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

But I am unable to get this into a new file name using zmv. Any suggestions in zsh shell? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `find`, use `zmv`. Use `( )` pairs to grab the bits of the filename you want, and `${1}`, `${2}` etc to reference them. Here's my folder structure:

```
$ ls **/*
Sample_1234/all_R2.gz  Sample_4567/all_R2.gz
Sample_2345/all_R2.gz  Sample_6890/all_R2.gz

Sample_1234:
all_R2.gz

Sample_2345:
all_R2.gz

Sample_4567:
all_R2.gz

Sample_6890:
all_R2.gz
```

And here's `zmv`, [assuming you've got it loaded](http://zshwiki.org/home/builtin/functions/zmv):

```
$ zmv -n 'Sample_(*)/all_R2.gz' 'Sample_${1}/${1}_R2.gz'
mv -- Sample_1234/all_R2.gz Sample_1234/1234_R2.gz
mv -- Sample_2345/all_R2.gz Sample_2345/2345_R2.gz
mv -- Sample_4567/all_R2.gz Sample_4567/4567_R2.gz
mv -- Sample_6890/all_R2.gz Sample_6890/6890_R2.gz
```

It grabs everything between the `_` and `/` in the filename *from the current directory*, which allows us to reference the number string at the end of the directory name. We then insert that back into the filename using `${1}` to reference, replacing `all`.

It's well worth using `zmv -n` to see what would happen before you do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't see until just now for some reason. Still helpful.